# How to create a filterable Dash datatable where the data comes from an uploader

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am attempting to create a datatable that can be filtered. The source of the data is pulled in after clicking the button, and this is what I am having trouble working around.

In my actual app, the data that populates the datatable is from an `uploader`, and substituting this for the button below produces the same error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

If I comment out `filter_action="native"`, it works fine.

```
from dash import dash, dash_table, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('start', id='button'),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable',
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        row_deletable=True,
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable', 'data'),
    Output('datatable', 'columns'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
)
def generate_upload_file(n_clicks):  
    if n_clicks:
        df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')
        data_dict = df.to_dict('records')
        headers_list = list(df.columns.values)
        headers_dict = ([{'id': _, 'name': _} for _ in headers_list])
        return data_dict, headers_dict
    else: raise PreventUpdate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your code this way?
I think directly return the table as a div children will be OK.

```
from dash import dash, dash_table, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('start', id='button'),
    html.Div(id='datatable')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable', 'children'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
)
def generate_upload_file(n_clicks):  
    if n_clicks:
        df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')
        data_dict = df.to_dict('records')
        headers_list = list(df.columns.values)
        headers_dict = ([{'id': _, 'name': _} for _ in headers_list])
        return dash_table.DataTable(
                data=data_dict,
                columns=headers_dict,
                filter_action="native",
                sort_action="native",
                sort_mode="multi",
                row_deletable=True,
                page_action="native",
                page_current= 0,
                page_size= 10,
            )
    else: raise PreventUpdate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: This works, thank you. My new problem is that there is another callback that later refers to this datatable. When I initially load the app, I get an 'ID not found in Layout' error, since the datatable is not yet created and the second callback it trying to find its ID. I have Prevent Update and Prevent Initial Callbacks in place.  How do I solve this?

Comment: It depends on how you design to trigger this action. Take this code as example, it is a button click so that we detect `n_clicks` > 0 to load this table. It can be like `some_contents is not None` if it is based on some upload content not to be empty (needs `id` and its content as input of the callback).